# BDC - Problems in applications

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss, bdc

I am getting some problems in the BDC applications.

When I import some BDCs application I get an empty error and my BDC applications in Central Administration file has no Version and no data. If I try to anything on it, I get Access Denied. Help!

I am trying to delete it, because i already fixed the BDC file.

Screenshots are here:

http://img30.imageshack.us/img30/6398/bdc.jpg

http://img44.imageshack.us/img44/3646/bdc1.jpg

Comment: Your prints/images are not visable

Answer (score 0):

Did you by chance also specify permissions in the Application Definition file?  If you did and you did not at least give one user or group admin access to the BDC application definition, you are pretty much stuck.  I have found that when this happens there is no way to delete the application definition from the BDC because no user has permission to modify it.